# Weird behaviour with escape of REGEX in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

Can you please explain me this behaviour?

```
mysql> SELECT *, ('http://www.thisisatest.es/?utm_source=xxxx&utm_term=&utm_campaign=xxxx&utm_medium=xxxx' REGEXP rule) r FROM containers_rules;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+
| rule                                                                                  | r    |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+
| ^http://www.thisisatest.es/\\?utm_source                                              |    0 |
| ^http://www.thisisatest.es/\?utm_source                                               |    1 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT 'http://www.thisisatest.es/?utm_source=xxxx&utm_term=&utm_campaign=xxxx&utm_medium=xxxx' REGEXP '^http://www.thisisatest.es/\\?utm_source' r;
+---+
| r |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I don't understand why a manual REGEX comparison needs two "\" and the dynamic REGEX comparison just one "\" or it won't work?

I am a bit lost...

Comment: Actually, the manual regex needs two backslashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result set that you're seeing shows the column values as is (i.e. without additional escape characters).

However, a string literal *does* require the additional backslash; for example, the insert statement for the second row would have been:

```
INSERT INTO ... VALUES ('^http://www.thisisatest.es/\\?utm_source')
```

And that matches your manual query.

Answer (score 1):

Using `\?` will match a *literal* question mark.
Using `\\?` will match zero or one (`?`) instances of a backslash `\`.

**As for your edit:**

When you have `^http://www.thisisatest.es/\?utm_source` stored in a database row, it will be understood as-is.
When you use `REGEXP '^http://www.thisisatest.es/\?utm_source'`, the escapes are substituted, meaning that the pattern is interpreted as `^http://www.thisisatest.es/?utm_source`, which is incorrect.  (It searches for zero or one `/`)

Comment: Then why does `SELECT 'http://www.thisisatest.es/?utm_source=xxxx&utm_term=&utm_campaign=xxxx&utm_medium=xxxx' REGEXP '^http://www.thisisatest.es/\?utm_source' r;` return 0?

Comment: Try doing `SELECT '^http://www.thisisatest.es/\?utm_source';` and you'll see why it doesn't match. Once you have the regex loaded into the database it no longer parses `\?` as `?`.  I'll edit my answer to elaborate.

Comment: Is the regex stored in the database as a string or a regex object? If it is a string it needs to be stored as `\\?` then add one more for the editor `'\\\?'` right?